# Setup process.env during runtime from kubernetes config for already builder docker react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes

I jump to the new team and they are trying to use one builded docker image for react UI app where some URLs are mapped to process.env variables. We have to somehow override these variables from kubernetes config. Is it even possible for builded react app docker image? If not, is there any best practices how to do it?

REACT_APP_BASE_URL is then undefined.

Thanks everybody for tips and hints.

My Yaml config:

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: web-ui
   namespace: web
 spec:
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: web-ui
     spec:
       containers:
         - env:
            - name: REACT_APP_BASE_URL
              value: "https://setitup.in.runtime.com"
         - image: myaws.eu-west.amazonaws.com/web-ui:latest
           name: my-web-ui
```

Comment: This question is really too broad for us to answer right now. If you can show us a specific pod or deployment manifest, and show how you're setting environment variables in the pod and explain what's not working as expected, we can probably help you out.

Comment: Added YAML config and I am building this docker image autoatically through pipeline config in bitbucket, the react app is builded running  `yarn run build` command

Comment: @M.P. the main issue with this approach is react application should be built with this value in variable. Your `yaml` is correct, env value will be presented in pod. But react app "won't see" it. Please refer to e.g. [environment files in react](https://dev.to/samirasaad/environment-variables-for-a-react-js-app-329j)